# Update values of a column in h:dataTable using ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable

my search for a solution did not provide anything helpful. So I'll ask my first question on stackoverflow.com - if I can do better in any way, please let me know.

The problem:
I need to update a column of a `<h:dataTable>` depending on the value in one of the `<h:inputText>` from another column in the same `dataTable`. The column is to be rendered when a `valueChange` is detected. After the column is rendered I want the focus to stay and not to reset and point to somewhere at the top of the page.

My solution(s) that are only half-working:
1.

```
<h:column>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.value}">
        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange"
            listener="#{myBean.updateColumn}" execute="@this"
            render="@form"></a4j:ajax>
    </h:inputText>
</h:column>
```

This results in the expected behaviour as the whole form is rendered. But this way I lose my focus, which is not user-friendly at all.

2.

```
<h:column>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.value}">
        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange"
            listener="#{myBean.updateColumn}" execute="@this"
            render="IdOfMyColumn"></a4j:ajax>
    </h:inputText>
</h:column>
```

This was my second attempt. I assigned an ID to my column, that is to the `<h:panelGroup>` in the column. Looking like this:

```
<h:column>
    <h:panelGroup id="IdOfMyColumn">
        <h:outputText value="#{myBean.updatedValue}">   
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:column>
```

This sadly results in only the row being updated. The exact row where I change a value. At least, the focus stays where it was.

So as you can see, my two solutions each solve one of my problems. Sadly I cannot figure out, how to combine them. I need a way to keep my focus using solution 1 with `render="@form"` or a way to update the whole column and not the single row.

Any help is appreciated! I'm using JSF 2.0 with Richfaces 4.3, deploying on IBM Portal Server (and cannot change this). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by myself! Writing down a problem helps solving it :)  Not too nice, but working in the desired way.

Instead of one single dataTable with different columns I use one dataTable per column. This way I can render the dataTables (with the single columns).

If you have suggestions to improve my solution, feel free.